# Found ddl change for a table in CDC management console

Tags: db2, ddl, oracle-cdc

our target db is DB2 and source is ORACLE, we found ddl changes in CDC management console and i need to fix the instance in to proper running condition.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Vernon answer assumes that what you are looking for is how to replicate DDL changes.  I will assume that you don't want to replicate DDL changes, but just restart the subscription after minor layout changes (for example, after a column size has been increased or a column you are not going to replicate, changes).

If that is the case, right-click the specific table map on your subscription, and update table definition. I am not sure but I think after that, you have to refresh the entire subscription.  If the table is very large, you will want to avoid refreshing them all, but that's another question.

Off course, if in the table change, a column has been added and you want to deal with it, you can edit column map and make the specific assignment you want to that column.

I hope this helps.